# Did Japanese officers refuse to engage in kamikaze attacks?

Tags: world-war-two, japan, ww2-pacific-theater

The Kamikaze is a military tactic that appeared officially in Japan's forces in 1944. This was used first by some officers, and then became more and more widespread.

My understanding of the Japanese army behaviour is that it was a very "officer-based" army: Officers had great power on their subordinates and autonomy on their decision, and often confronted with each other.
See from examples:

- [The Mukden incident](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mukden_Incident)
- [U-Go offensive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Kohima)

Another point is that, from my previous research, there was testimonies of Japanese, even Kamikaze pilots, that disagree with this tactic.

Considering these elements, I'm wondering whether frontal or passive opposition occurred from Japanese commanding officers?

**Definition:**

- Commanding officer: An officer commanding at least a few men in a unit, who would be in charge of organizing the Kamikaze attack had it been ordered
- Frontal opposition: An officer saying to a commanding or fellow officer: "No, I won't engage myself and/or my men in the Kamikaze attack"
- Passive opposition: An officer saying "Yes" but delaying or never engaging the Kamikaze attack

Answer (score 8):

According to Wikipedia, some officers, such as Yoshio Shiga, Tadashi Minobe, and Minoru Genda [all refused to carry out such policies.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kamikaze#Cultural_background)
Other officers criticized the method and concept but still carried out the policy, notably Iyozo Fujita.
**As a bonus:** the majority of Japanese pilots and officers who engaged in the attacks [later regretted it](https://www.iol.co.za/amp/mercury/news/world/japans-kamikaze-pilots-regret-survival-3108b328-4756-5646-8546-716ea7197d30), one official saying, [“I think of the many men I killed with my pencil, and I apologize for having killed them in vain](https://apnews.com/article/06f0f9d45abf41e5a3a5ebfde19582f6)", and with another writing that young people should ["not follow my example. That's what I want to leave with young people today.](https://mainichi.jp/english/articles/20191122/p2a/00m/0fe/017000c)